# Why 200ms is popular as acceptable response time?

Tags: performance, scalability, response-time

So many articles and books that talk about application performance quote 200 ms as an example of acceptable response time.

I am curious how this 200 ms arrived at? Why is it not 100 ms or 300 ms? What is the rationale behind 200 ms? Is it driven by current capabilities and constraints of hardware/network etc?

Comment: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/1664/what-is-the-threshold-where-actions-are-perceived-as-instant

Comment: IOW: 200ms is just another example of people having low standards wrt. responsiveness. Ideally, aim for a single frame delay.